# One of my 3 pin socket is not working

Tags: electrical, uk, socket

[image: socket]

I have a dual 3 pin plug socket which one of them is not working now. Previously, all I had to do was to kind of palm-slap onto the plug of my laptop a couple of times to get it working and sometimes would hear some small electrifying noises but as the time goes, the method gradually became useless.

What should I do now? Should I go get another dual 3 pin plug socket faceplate or there could be something else wrong with the whole electrical wiring system?

Thanks!

Comment: These symptoms of poor and unsafe construction are why I would avoid cheap Chinese-made sockets containing USB sockets. The USB sockets might not be stable or properly isolated from 240V AC. See [A look inside a (crap) double gang socket with USB outlets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoZ1_aEDPos) by Big Clive.

Answer (score 4):

the "electric noises" is very likely arcing.

If the other one works normally then the fix is to replace the entire outlet (the face plate is just a cosmetic cover).

Comment: UK sockets don't normally have separate face-plates (unlike American ones)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with two three pin sockets – I could not get the plug into the 45-year old sockets.  Instead of replacing the sockets (which can de done by an electrician) I plugged in cheap two-way adapters.  Then I could plug in to the adapter.  I suppose that the three pin fittings, in a cheap adapter, are more flexible allowing them to fit into a socket and to take three pin plugs more easily.  My problems are solved – and cheaply!